# para que sirve el comando ./ en cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, shell, powershell

estoy utilizando un codigo que vi en github en lenguaje shell pero necesito escribir `./` y algunas cosas pero al escribirlo me arroja el error `"." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable` (utilizo windows) eso se utilizará para otro sistema operativo?

Comment: por favor muéstranos tú código

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para separar nombres de directorios en Windows se usa la barra invertida `\` y en Linux se usa la barra diagonal `/`. Por tanto, te diría que tu código o comando es para Linux.

Por otra parte, el `.` es la abreviatura de `source` en sistemas Unix, es decir, ejecuta comandos de un fichero en el entorno o contexto en el que se encuentra.

Comment: En windows se puede escribir ./myscript.ps1  para correr un script en el directorio corriente.

Comment: Si lo haces desde la consola CMD de Windows, no te reconocerá el comando con `/`. Imagino que lo estas lanzando desde Windows PowerShell el cual utiliza cmdlets en PowerShell.

Comment: `.` solo abrevia `source` si se usa como `. archivo.bash`, en el caso de `./archivo`, es decir, usado como parte de la ruta, es un enlace al directorio actual, como `..` es un enlace al directorio superior en la jerarquía. El caso del OP **no** es una abreviatura de `source`.

Answer (score 1):

Windows dentro de su consola (CMD) utiliza la barra invertida `\` para separar entre carpetas, mientras que en linux se utiliza la barra convencional `/`.

Lo que estas diciendo al utilizar `./` en Linux es que a partir de la carpeta actual hacia donde continuar, su equivalente en Windows seria `.\`

Ej: Directorio actual `C:\` -> Moverme a Archivos de programa `cd ".\Archivos de programa'`